# How to precise the results of SPARQL CONSTRUCT query?

Tags: sparql, rdf

The query is supposed to return foaf:name of E21_Person where mus:U31_had_function is "composer". But the result returns all the foaf:name without filtering the function.

This is the query that I run:

```
CONSTRUCT {?F22_Self_Contained_Expression foaf:name ?composerName; mus:U41_has_catalogue_number ?catalogueNumber}
WHERE {
?F22_Self_Contained_Expression mus:U16_has_catalogue_statement/ecrm:P3_has_note ?catalogueNumber.
?F28_Expression_Creation efrbroo:R17_created ?F22_Self_Contained_Expression;
ecrm:P9_consists_of/ecrm:P14_carried_out_by/foaf:name ?composerName.
```

The data structure is the following:

```
<http://data.doremus.org/artist/adebc97e-fd15-3094-b15b-a7443c26497f>
        a                           ecrm:E21_Person ;
        rdfs:label                  "Francesco Maria Piave" ;
        ecrm:P100i_died_in          <http://data.doremus.org/artist/adebc97e-fd15-3094-b15b-a7443c26497f/death> ;
        ecrm:P131_is_identified_by  "Piave, Francesco Maria (1810-1876)" ;
        ecrm:P98i_was_born          <http://data.doremus.org/artist/adebc97e-fd15-3094-b15b-a7443c26497f/birth> ;
        schema:birthDate            "1810"^^xsd:gYear ;
        schema:deathDate            "1876"^^xsd:gYear ;
        foaf:firstName              "Francesco Maria" ;
        foaf:name                   "Francesco Maria Piave" ;
        foaf:surname                "Piave" .

<http://data.doremus.org/event/f7c6dbae-581e-3ac7-9d8e-d0f4d21d0fcf>
        a                    efrbroo:F28_Expression_Creation ;
        efrbroo:R17_created  <http://data.doremus.org/expression/a92f029b-4616-325a-b526-52ec3a8e3a5c> ;
        efrbroo:R19_created_a_realisation_of
                <http://data.doremus.org/work/599f63b9-47ad-3591-993a-6729dc6b1cca> .

<http://data.doremus.org/event/dde04c04-5e86-3583-9f8f-8adfcbbf2564/activity/3>
        a                        ecrm:E7_Activity ;
        mus:U31_had_function     <http://data.doremus.org/vocabulary/function/librettist> ;
        ecrm:P14_carried_out_by  <http://data.doremus.org/artist/adebc97e-fd15-3094-b15b-a7443c26497f> .

<http://data.doremus.org/event/dde04c04-5e86-3583-9f8f-8adfcbbf2564/activity/2>
        a                        ecrm:E7_Activity ;
        mus:U31_had_function     <http://data.doremus.org/vocabulary/function/librettist> ;
        ecrm:P14_carried_out_by  <http://data.doremus.org/artist/b82c0771-5280-39af-ad2e-8ace2f4ebda3> .

<http://data.doremus.org/event/dde04c04-5e86-3583-9f8f-8adfcbbf2564/activity/1>
        a                        ecrm:E7_Activity ;
        mus:U31_had_function     <http://data.doremus.org/vocabulary/function/composer> ;
        ecrm:P14_carried_out_by  <http://data.doremus.org/artist/b82c0771-5280-39af-ad2e-8ace2f4ebda3> .

<http://data.doremus.org/artist/b82c0771-5280-39af-ad2e-8ace2f4ebda3>
        a                           ecrm:E21_Person ;
        rdfs:label                  "Giuseppe Verdi" ;
        ecrm:P100i_died_in          <http://data.doremus.org/artist/b82c0771-5280-39af-ad2e-8ace2f4ebda3/death> ;
        ecrm:P131_is_identified_by  "Verdi, Giuseppe (1813-1901)" ;
        ecrm:P98i_was_born          <http://data.doremus.org/artist/b82c0771-5280-39af-ad2e-8ace2f4ebda3/birth> ;
        schema:birthDate            "1813"^^xsd:gYear ;
        schema:deathDate            "1901"^^xsd:gYear ;
        foaf:firstName              "Giuseppe" ;
        foaf:name                   "Giuseppe Verdi" ;
        foaf:surname                "Verdi" .
```

I expect the output of foaf:name for the person whose function is "composer"

Comment: you can't use the property path `ecrm:P9_consists_of/ecrm:P14_carried_out_by/foaf:name` here because the composer function is attached to the node after the `P9_consists_of` property.

Comment: please try `?F28_Expression_Creation ecrm:P9_consists_of ?tmp . ?tmp  mus:U31_had_function     <http://data.doremus.org/vocabulary/function/composer> ;
         ecrm:P14_carried_out_by/foaf:name ?composerName`

Comment: I am running the query for a database, which contains information of different entries. Now, when I run this query it returns all the names of the composers, and not the one that corresponds to the 
 mus:U16_has_catalogue_statement/ecrm:P3_has_note.  The result I get now is: mus:U41_has_catalogue_number  "IHW 15" ;
        foaf:name                     "Scott Joplin" , "Johann Adolf Hasse" , "Enno Poppe" , "Nat Simon" , "Philippe Hurel" , "James Mobberley" , "Gerardo Di Giusto" , "Jörg Widmann" , "Carl Heinrich Graun" , "Karol Beffa" , "Neal Hefti" , "Jean-Christophe Béney" , ...

Comment: I can't help here without seeing a complete sample of the data. In your question, you do not show how catalogue number is connected to the other data.

Comment: I tired it, for "IHW 15" I get only "Hugo Wolf" - not sure if this is correct, I'm not a domain expert. MY query: `CONSTRUCT {
?s foaf:name ?composerName; 
mus:U41_has_catalogue_number ?catalogueNumber
} WHERE {
VALUES ?catalogueNumber { "IHW 15"}
?s mus:U16_has_catalogue_statement/ecrm:P3_has_note ?catalogueNumber.
?s1 efrbroo:R17_created ?s;
ecrm:P9_consists_of ?tmp . 
?tmp mus:U31_had_function <http://data.doremus.org/vocabulary/function/composer> ; 
ecrm:P14_carried_out_by/foaf:name ?composerName
}` - so I assume my query is correct. For completeness, just remove the `VALUES`